# error-adding-node-to-odl-via-restconf/

Tags: opendaylight

I'm trying to add a `netconf-connector` into my Open Daylight Nitrogen controller and keep coming up against this error:

">Error parsing input: Could not find module for namespace urn:opendaylight:params:xml:ns:yang:controller:md:sal:connector:netconf"

I'm posting to rest via the postman application using the below URL and Schema used in the guide below:

"http://192.168.0.1:8181/restconf/config/network-topology:network-topology/topology/topology-netconf/node/controller-config/yang-ext:mount/config:modules"

Has anyone had the same issue, this is the guide I'm following..

http://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-nitrogen/user-guide/netconf-user-guide.html

I found the same issue reported on the old Open Daylight forum but it went un-answered..

https://ask.opendaylight.org/question/28561/error-adding-node-to-odl-via-restconf/

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: Paste the question here with example of codes please.

Comment: I'm unable to paste the code as it's exceeds the maximum character limit. In my question is a link to the OD forum where another user with the same issue asked the same question, but it went unanswered and now the forum is read only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the error message, you tried to use the controller-config loopback mechanism. This mechanism was deprecated and I believe was completely removed in Nitrogen (unfortunately the documentation wasn't updated to indicate this). Either way, you should use the mechanism outlined in the "Netconf-connector configuration with MD-SAL" section.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for your help, I will give this a go!